# Escaping raw html in blade template files

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i hope you're having a good day.

i have some raw html that i want to render inside my blade file,

ive tried the `{!!...!!}` syntax but for some reason it is not working for me, when i use this

```php
  { !! $jobs[0]->content !!}
```

i get this result

[image]

My laravel version is >8.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The syntax is without the space. `{!! $jobs[0]->content !!}`

Comment: @Marwelln yours worked, consider answering so i can accept and vote ur answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is without the space. Removing your leading space will solve your issue.

```
{!! $jobs[0]->content !!}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data